# How to compare two forms based on condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am creating form through drag and drop facility and i am saving it in one variable. like following

```
var addform = '<form method="POST" name="1" class="form-horizontal wpc_contact" novalidate="novalidate">                        
   <div class="controls" style="border:0px">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" class="input-xlarge" req="yes" name="First Name"> 
  </div>

  <div class="controls" style="border:0px">     
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="Last Name" class="input-xlarge" req="no">        
  </div>                        

  <div class="controls" style="border:0px" name="Contact time" req="yes">         
    <label class="checkbox inline">         
        <input type="checkbox" value="Day" name="Contact time" id="Contact time_0" req="yes">Day        
    </label>        
    <label class="checkbox inline">          
        <input type="checkbox" value="Night" name="Contact time" id="Contact time_1" req="yes">Night
    </label>        
    <label class="checkbox inline">          
        <input type="checkbox" value="Any" name="Contact time" id="Contact time_2" req="yes"> Any       
    </label>    
  </div>                    

  <div class="controls" style="border:0px">  
    <textarea style="min-height: 100px" placeholder="Enter Message" class="input-xlarge" req="yes" name="Message">
    </textarea>                               
  </div>                    

  <div class="controls" style="border:0px">     
    <button class="btn btn-success">Send</button>       
  </div>                
</form>';
```

when user is editing same form through same way (drag and drop way) i am saving it in another variable like following

```
var editform = '<form method="POST" name="1" class="form-horizontal wpc_contact" novalidate="novalidate">                       

<div class="controls" style="border:0px">   
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="Last Name" class="input-xlarge" req="no">        
</div>                          

<div class="controls" style="border:0px" name="Contact time" req="yes">         
    <label class="checkbox inline">         
        <input type="checkbox" value="Day" name="Contact time" id="Contact time_0" req="yes">Day        
    </label>        
    <label class="checkbox inline">          
        <input type="checkbox" value="Night" name="Contact time" id="Contact time_1" req="yes">Night
    </label>        
    <label class="checkbox inline">          
        <input type="checkbox" value="Any" name="Contact time" id="Contact time_2" req="yes"> Any       
    </label>    
</div>                      

<div class="controls" style="border:0px">  
    <textarea style="min-height: 100px" placeholder="Enter Message" class="input-xlarge" req="yes" name="Message">
    </textarea>                               
</div>                      

 <div class="controls" style="border:0px">      
    <button class="btn btn-success">Send</button>       
 </div>                 
</form> ';
```

now my question is how do i compare both variable based on user has **added/removed** any **input element** while editing..

in above case while editing i have removed first name input element so it should say **"you have removed one element from form"**.

i don't know is it possible through javascript/jquery or not? please guide me on this

Thanks

Comment: Why not compare (by checking values of controls) before adding the html in second variable? That would be easier and would be the proper way.

Comment: I would make an array of the input IDs, and compare them rather than trying to compare HTML strings.

Comment: If not that way, you can still create a JQuery variable using those two `html`s and then compare the controls in the two forms.

Comment: @P5Coder can you give me some more detail? what exactly you are suggesting?

Comment: Surely you might be taking the form's html (after the user has done with the editing) and putting it in the second variable. before that, you should check if the controls are same as that were before, using simple jquery.

Comment: ohh that way i can do.. can you give me one small example code so i can start with it

Answer (score 1):

If there are only `div`s, `input`s, etc. some common controls that are going to be editted, you can do something like this:

```
var form1 = $(addform);
var form2 = $(editform);
if(form1.find('div').length != form2.find('div').length)
    alert('There is change in number of divs.');
// and so on...
```

Or you can traverse the tree structure of both the forms (using the above method) simultaneously until there is some change found or end of children.

Comment: please have look http://jsbin.com/loyuv/1/edit its not working it seems using class name

Answer (score 0):

First break it by \n to form an Array of lines and then compare both of them line by line and then when you able to find difference then find the difference between unmatched lines and finally display it as output.

Comment: it should raise error only when i have added/removed any of input type or textarea or readio button. it should not raise error in case i am going to change input name,id or and div name or id

Comment: The solution that I have given can be programmed for any case.I designed whole file compare tool on frontend side using this logic.